# How can we use sum and max at the same time when group by data?

Tags: mainframe, jcl

How can we sum amount and get max date at the same time when group by id in JCL

Input:

```
Id   Amount Date
--------------------
123  200    20180516
123  300    20180520
456  100    20180616
456  700    20180420
```

Expected result:

```
Id   Amount Date
--------------------
123  500    20180520
456  800    20180616
```

What i try already:

```
SORTST5  EXEC PGM=SORT
SYSOUT   DD   SYSOUT=*
SYSPRINT DD   SYSOUT=*
SORTIN   DD   DSN=&VNTMPççWRK.INWORK,DISP=SHR
SORTOUT  DD   DSN=&VNTMP..WRK.OUTWORK.OUT.FRM,
              DISP=(,CATLG,DELETE),
              RECFM=FB,LRECL=84, SPACE=(CYL,(100,100), RLSE)
SYSIN    DD   *
SORT FIELDS=(1,3,PD,A)
SUM  FIELDS=(4,3,PD)
```

Comment: Please show us the JCL and control statements you have tried already, and the results that you got.

Comment: I add my last code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JCL isn't an executable and you can't manipulate date in JCL without utilities like SORT.

I've used ICETOOL (a utility) in JCL to achieve your expected result.
First Control statement will sort the Input using ID (in ascending order) and Date (in descending order). Second control statement will do SUM FIELDS on the output yielded using first control statement.

```
//STEP1    EXEC PGM=ICETOOL                    
//TOOLMSG  DD SYSOUT=*                       
//DFMSG    DD SYSOUT=*                         
//TOOLIN   DD *                               
  SORT FROM(INDD) TO(OUTDD1) USING(CTL1)    
  SORT FROM(OUTDD1) TO(OUTDD2) USING(CTL2)  
//INDD     DD *                                 
123 200 20180516                            
123 300 20180520                            
456 700 20180420                            
456 100 20180616                            
//OUTDD1   DD DSN=XXX.ICETOOL.OUTDD1,         
//         DISP=(,CATLG,DELETE),              
//         SPACE=(CYL,(100,0),RLSE),          
//         DCB=(LRECL=80,RECFM=FB,BLKSIZE=0)  
//OUTDD2   DD DSN=XXX.ICETOOL.OUTDD2,         
//         DISP=(,CATLG,DELETE),              
//         SPACE=(CYL,(100,0),RLSE),          
//         DCB=(LRECL=80,RECFM=FB,BLKSIZE=0)  
//SSMSG    DD SYSOUT=*                         
//SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=*                        
//CTL1CNTL DD *                             
 SORT FIELDS=(1,3,ZD,A,9,8,ZD,D)            
/*                                          
//CTL2CNTL DD *                             
 SORT FIELDS=(1,3,ZD,A)                     
 SUM FIELDS=NONE                            
/*
```